# What is the approach to integrate identity functionality into a .net api?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a .net api with couple of endpoints. It will eventually be used by mobile apps and web apps.

In the database I have already got a table containing the user's id(integer), name, email. And other tables that have the user related business data with the user's id as foreign key.

Now I want to add identity functionality to it. For example: register, login, and reset password.

Reading this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

> ASP.NET Core Identity:
>
> Is an API that supports user interface (UI) login functionality.
> Manages users, passwords, profile data, roles, claims, tokens, email
> confirmation, and more.

Question 1:
It doesn't say anything about whether it can be added to an api. And in that scenario - assuming the api is used by a mobile app, how will functionality like reset password work? Will there be a web page generated into my web api?

Further the article says:

> ASP.NET Core Identity adds user interface (UI) login functionality to
> ASP.NET Core web apps. To secure web APIs and SPAs, use one of the
> following:
>
> Azure Active Directory Azure Active Directory B2C (Azure AD B2C)
> IdentityServer4

Question 2:
So is it possible to add identity to an api but not recommended to do so?

Question 3:
The IdentityServer4 link takes me to an external page so is it recommended to use an external provider?

Question 4:
1 option I have is to create endpoints for login, register, etc and implement the login functionality through code. The 2nd option is to have the login, register endpoints make use of .net identity, but then if I use a Oauth provider then what is it point of .net identity?

Question 5:
Is there any other recommended option?

Answer (score 0):

you can use  **identity server 4**
OR
use **Jwt**
If you want to use it for user authentication, have a login